# btrfs RAID1 - does adding a 3rd HD add data security?

Tags: raid-1, btrfs

would spanning a btrfs RAID1 over 3 drives allow for 2 drives to fail, before data loss?

Or in other words ... "is a btrfs RAID1 on 3 drives more data save then one with 2 drives"?

---

**EDIT:** or would you gain space with same data safety level. So is a 3 drive btrfs RAID ...

#### A) more datasave

- **2 x 2TB** drives RAID1 = **2TB** space (**1 hd** can fail before data loss)
- **3 x 2TB** drives RAID1 = **2TB** space (**2 hds** can fail before data loss)

or

#### B) more space

- **2 x 2TB** drives RAID1 = **2TB** space (**1 hd** can fail before data loss)
- **3 x 2TB** drives RAID1 = **3TB** space (**1 hd** can fail before data loss)

.....

P.S. I don't care much about hotswap capabilities. Can stop the server for exchanging a failed drive if necessary

Comment: Spanning RAID 1 over more than 2 drives just leaves more drives powered on. If you have an event that damages two drives then it has likely been catastrophic enough to flatten the entire system.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams my scenario is drive failure due to **bad, or old drives, not outside catastrophic impact**. For example if 1 drive fails cause it's old do can I still wait for the 2nd to fail (cause that's also old) before I loose data ?

Comment: Then you gain nothing by having a third hot. Put it as a warm spare, or better yet pull it from the chassis and use it for backup.

Comment: thanks @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams. honestly I don't understand much of what you're saying :-(. What do you mean by 'hot', what's a 'warm spare'? I'm afraid I have difficulties to follow half sentences due to lack of understanding of the matter. I can afford to shut down the server for exchanging drives it that's what you're aiming at (even though that wasn't really my question).

Comment: @vrms A hot spare is a disk that is not in use in your RAID but is connected and configured to jump in automatically when needed. A cold spare is not connected but in reach, e.g. in the same building not needing to be shipped from another site. Not clear where exactly to draw the line but relying on a hardware supplier to deliver a replacement definitely does not count as having a spare. "Warm spare" is not clearly defined, sometimes synonymous to hot spare, sometimes meaning that some commands or even a reboot are needed to add the disk, but no physical work as for a cold spare.

Answer (score 1):

For those arriving from the future, in version 5.5 you can use RAID1C3 or RAID1C4 with 3 or 4 copies, which will result in resiliency for 2 or 3 drive failures.

Source: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Using-Btrfs-RAID1C3-RAID1C4

Answer (score 0):

found a convincing answer for *"does adding a 3rd harddisk to a btrfs RAID1 allow failure of 2 disks before data loss?"* elswhere

> *No. btrfs RAID1 means 2 copies of data on different devices. **Losing two devices may result in data loss depending on how exactly data is distributed over devices.** In practice you will most likely lose some data; if you are unlucky, it will be metadata and catastrophic loss of almost everything.*

considering this as answered now. Thanks everybody